# Vector identity in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: vectors, euclidean-geometry

I was told there exists an identity of the following type:
$$
\frac{A-B}{|A-B|^2}\cdot\frac{A-C}{|A-C|^2}+\frac{B-A}{|B-A|^2}\cdot\frac{B-C}{|B-C|^2}+\frac{C-A}{|C-A|^2}\cdot\frac{C-B}{|C-B|^2}=\frac{const}{R_{A,B,C}},
$$
where $A,B,C$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $R_{A,B,C}$ is the radius of the circle passing through $A,B,C$. Can anybody confirm this and/or give me a reference for that?

Comment: This cannot be true as stated: If you multiply $A$, $B$, $C$ by a constant $\lambda>0$ the LHS is divided by $\lambda^2$ and the RHS  by $\lambda$.

Comment: You are right, $R_{A,B,C}$ should probably be squared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WLOG the centre of the circle is the origin.  Take $A = r [\cos(\alpha),\sin(\alpha)]$, $B = r [\cos(\beta), \sin(\beta)]$, $C = r [\cos(\gamma),\sin(\gamma)]$, so $R_{A,B,C} = r$.  Then after some calculation the left side simplifies to 
$ 1/(2 r^2)$.